# How can I get current queue in emberJs?

Tags: ember.js, queue

tell me please, how can I debug queues in Ember.js and get current queue with "debugger;"?

Comment: It would help to know which queue you're talking about. Internally Ember uses a lot of queues. Very few of them are actually part of the public API.

Answer (score 2):

You can get current queue by inspecting:

```
Ember.run.currentRunLoop.queues
```

You'll notice you have many queues there:

> Object {sync: Queue, actions: Queue, routerTransitions: Queue, render:
>   Queue, afterRender: Queue…}

You have to expand each property which is a `Queue`, for example, `actions` and see if it has `_queueBeingFlushed` property defined. If yes, then it is current `Queue`.

Example of `_queueBeingFlushed` for `actions Queue`:

```
_queueBeingFlushed: Array[4]
0: null
1: ()
2: undefined
3: undefined
length: 4
```

When you know that you can also filter `Ember.run.currentRunLoop.queues` and get current `Queue` programatically.

[image: developer tools]